# Refactoring god class with dependency injection

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

**What am I refactoring**

```
/* core library code that i am forced to accept */

class God
{
    virtual void requestSacrifice()  { /* secret sauce */ }
    virtual void handlePrayers(Prayers const&);
    /* ... a few dozen more handlers and it is hopeless to raise a PR
 to extract each handle calls into a separate svc, even if they are logically separable */
}

/* my code / inherited code */

class Mustang: public God
{
   PrayersSvc prayersHandler;

   Mustang(): prayersHandler(this) {}

   void requestSacrifice() override;
   void handlePrayers(Prayers const& prayers) override { 
        God::handlePrayers(prayers);
        prayersHandler.handlePrayers( prayers ); 
   }
}

class PrayersSvc
{
   God* god;

   PrayerSvc(God* god): god(god) {}

   void handlePrayers(Prayers const& prayers) {
     //... logic
     god->requestSacrifice();
   }
}
```

Code smells that I am trying to solve:

1. `Mustang` violates SRP and it's in my codebase
2. `God*` gets (manually-)passed around.

**What hardness am I facing**

1. All entry points lies within `God` and that causes cyclic dependency -- `God` always have dependency on `PrayerSvc` as a handler, `PrayerSvc` always have dependency on `God` for the secret sauce entry point.
2. Dependency injection frameworks like Boost::DI and Google Fruit doesn't allow passing the `this` pointer in the middle of one constructor.

Comment: `God* gets (manually-)passed around.` as long as it's a non-owning (observer) pointer, I don't see a major problem. OK, maybe it could be made a reference if it's always non-null to prevent deletion/optional<reference_wrapper<God>> if it can actually be empty.

Comment: whats your specific question?

Comment: I'm not clear about your design idea anyway. What's the purpose of this `PrayerSvc` at all? Why cannot `God` implement that functionality directly?

Comment: What's the relation between `God` and `PrayerSvc`? 1to1 means either can own the other by composition. Many to 1 can be represented by 1 container per many...

Comment: main concern is test-ability -- virtually any Service that I develop will depend on some handler provided by God

Comment: specific question: Apply dependency injection to the code -- currently I cannot bind implementations because of the circular implementation

Comment: reason to have `PrayerSvc` is for SRP -- currently the actual `Mustang` has tens of thousands of lines and its no fun maintaining it for my daily work

Comment: There is very little logical relationship between `God` / `PrayerSvc`, `God` is supposed to be a router with proprietary logic implemented, `PrayerSvc` is supposed to be a worker that runs part of the workflow and pass the results back to `God` for the next leg of the workflow

Comment: @alagner to make it sound worse -- practically speaking god pointer is getting passed around for 50+ classes and i would attribute that to the reason why these 50+ class is not automate-tested -- it owns too much to be spawned in a test environment, and gets extended too frequently for the test environment implementation to hold ( because the `God` class devs don't give a flying crap about automate testing )

Comment: If  `God` is too big and therefore impractical to maintain mocks, can it be hidden behind a set of classes that expose just a subset of its interface?